# Реально ли создать биткоин кошелёк на php?

Tags: php, blockchain

Реально ли создать биткоин кошелёк на php? Обрыл интернет в поиске каких-то инструкций или понятной документации, но не понял удастся ли мне это на php?
Я имею ввиду сервис для создания кошельков, истории транзакций и переводов.

p.s.
Спасибо.
Как выйдет - прикреплю ссылку на гит в посте

Comment: Реально. Не понятно только, что вы имеете ввиду под кошельком

Comment: Дополнил, спасибо за комментарий.

Comment: Возможно, но не стоит делать это на php, мол он не удобный\медленный

Comment: Я так понимаю что для работы с сетью нужен демон сети для генерации адресов, верно? Если реализовать просто на php разве что просто создавать кошелёк на каком-то сервисе типа coinbase?

Comment: Что посоветуете?

Comment: Каким образом ваш ответ поможет автору? То, что php медленный никак не вредит здесь.

Comment: Хроническая нелюбовь к php видимо.

Comment: Я дал совет, а решать это вам, почему это. Я не то что люблю - пишу на PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ. Запускаете [bitcoind](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoind). С PHP отправляете JSON-RPC [команды](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list), примеры есть в [вики](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#PHP). Но вам придется разобраться, как все работает, что такое адрес/транзакция/блок и т. д.

Comment: В теории знаю как это работает. Спасибо большое за полезный ответ и информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо Вы имеете ввиду получение платежей в биткоинах на биткоин кошелек написать на php?
Если да, то нужно использовать API - [CryptoKick.app](https://cryptokick.app)

Там же есть примеры, как на php все сделать, для организации приема платежей в биткоинах на Вашем сайте.

Comment: Вопрос решен, и задача в большей степени была - хранить кошелек локально, используя bitcoind я решил этот вопрос