# Запуск bitcoind в Windows и подключение по rpc?

Tags: php, windows, bitcoin

Ранее в своём [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/836087/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php) я выяснил что мне нужен bitcoind.
Прочитав [вики](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoind) я скачал Bitcoin Core.
За тем дня 4 шла загрузка сети.(200+гб).
Имеем: Окно Bitcoin Core кошелька, там всё ок, Всё работает, кошелёк создаёт.
В диспетчере не обнаружил самого bitcoind. В директории с загруженной сетью лежал пустой файл bitcoin.conf, ну что ж, я его наполнил.
по 8332 подключиться не смог.

```
listen=1
maxconnections=15
server=1
daemon=1
rpcuser=myusername
rpcpassword=mypassword
rpcclienttimeout=60
rpcport=8332
```

Пытаюсь из под cmd запустить bitcoind.
Имею:
**Error: Unable to start HTTP server. See debug log for details.**
Иду в C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin, создаю bitcoin, снова наполняю. Запускаю из под консоли bitcoind, имею:
**Error: -daemon is not supported on this operating system**

Вопрос, как запустить демона?

При запуске bitcoin-cli -getinfo, информацию о сети/кошельке получаю.

```
{
  "version": 160000,
  "protocolversion": 70015,
  "walletversion": 159900,
  "balance": 0.00000000,
  "blocks": 526288,
  "timeoffset": 19,
  "connections": 8,
  "proxy": "",
  "difficulty": 4940704885521.827,
  "testnet": false,
  "keypoololdest": 1527945728,
  "keypoolsize": 1000,
  "paytxfee": 0.00000000,
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "warnings": ""
}
```

upd1: Нашёл [либу](https://github.com/denpamusic/php-bitcoinrpc) для работы с bitcoind на php.

upd2: Возможно проблема из-за того что bitcoin core запущен на удалённом компе

upd3: на локальном компьютере ок

**up4: rpcallowip=188.163.3.43 решил проблему с подключением с моего ip. Вопрос - как задать возможность подключения с нескольких или со всех ip?**

Comment: `Error: Unable to start HTTP server. See debug log for details` а что в логе? Вы ведь не пытаетесь запустить демон вместе с UI кошельком?

Comment: Все верно, в этом пожалуй была и ошибка. Кстати, прошарил логи и за актуальное время не нашёл нигде ошибок. При работе UI кошелька всё ок. Проблема с подключением с другими ip адресами. Обновил вопрос

Comment: Возможность подключатся со всех IP убрали давно: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/4894

Comment: Вы можете указать адресс и маску подсети

Comment: Спасибо! Проблема решена!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил **rpcallowip=188.163.3.43** в bitcoin.conf, всё работает!